# angular 5, http.get is ok but http.patch with same parameters returns 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: http, http-status-code-404, patch, angular5

I work with Angular 5.
I use a json for data.
I use very often http.get and it always works fine.
But http.patch returns an ERROR 404 NOT FOUND !
Does anybody can explain to me why ?

My config:
Angular CLI: 1.5.0
Node: 6.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.0.0

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Constants } from '../shared/classes/constantes/fr/constants';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app--test',
  templateUrl: './-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./-test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  id: number;
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.id = 3;
    this.latitude = 44.7637;
    this.longitude = -0.5536;
    const body = {
      'latitude': this.latitude,
      'longitude': this.longitude
    };

      this.http.get(Constants.USERS_URL + '?id=' + this.id).subscribe(data => {
      const userLogged = data;
      if (!userLogged[0]) {
        // NEVER HAPPENS : IT'S OK
      } else {
        this.http.patch(Constants.USERS_URL + '?id=' + this.id, body).subscribe();
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: sorry, thus was meant to be an editing comment, not a comment here. I added some newlines in your question

Comment: my db.json :
"users": [{
            "id": 3,
            "latitude": 0,
            "longitude": 0,
            "email": "jean.dupont@undefined.net",
            "name": {
                "first": "Jean",
                "last": "Dupont"
            }
        }
    ],

Comment: no problem, just edit this into your question if you want. and you can also delete your own comments if needed. I'll delete my first one too.